# Rails: Naming Many Variables with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I'm using FactoryGirl with my Rspec testings and I need to create many users, but I also need to be able to name them so I can reference them.  However, when I'm naming them I keep getting an error.

```
# in my request spec
21.times do |u|
  "user_#{u}" = FactoryGirl.create(:user, counter: "#{u}")
end
```

I have tried `"user_#{u}".to_sym` and `"user_#{u}".constantize` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
users = Array.new
21.times do |u|
  users << FactoryGirl.create(:user, counter: "#{u}")
end
```

and access each user by:

```
users[your_desired_index]
```